# Imshow/Matshow shrink inside axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I want to plot a matrix of numbers (as done via `matshow`/`imshow`). I then want to  draw "on the axes boundaries" some function that relates to the axes.

However: I'd like the `matshow` output to have a black boundary box, but it appears I can't control that with `edge_color` and `line_width`. Secondly, both commands appear to "shrink" the resulting axes, such that axes + ticks + labels all fit inside the axes. However, this misaligns the plot with what I want to draw on the boundaries.

In particular, have a look at the following picture. The density plot above the `matshow` has the same grid as the `x-axis` grid from the `matshow`, but it doesn't fully span it. Also, it misses the black box around the `matshow`.

How can I add/fix those two features?

[image: incorrect output]

Here's my current code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('ggplot')
nX, nY = 50, 70
realXGrid = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, nX)
realYGrid = np.linspace(-1, 1, nY)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(realXGrid, realYGrid, indexing='ij')
Z = XX * 3 - YY*5

# prepare figure/grid
fig5 = plt.figure()
widths = [1, 0.1, 0.1]
heights = [0.1, 1]
matAx = 3
caxAx = 5
spec5 = fig5.add_gridspec(ncols=3, nrows=2, width_ratios=widths,
                      height_ratios=heights, hspace=0, wspace=0)
axes = []
for row in range(2):
    for col in range(3):
        ax = fig5.add_subplot(spec5[row, col])
        axes.append(ax)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    if i != matAx:
        ax.axis('off')
    else:
        ax.grid(False)
        ax.patch.set_edgecolor('black')
        ax.patch.set_linewidth('1')

# plot
cax = axes[matAx].imshow(Z, cmap='RdGy', origin='lower')
axes[matAx].axis('image')
fig5.colorbar(cax, ax=axes[caxAx], orientation='vertical', fraction=1)

xDensity = norm.pdf(realXGrid, scale=0.1)
yDensity = norm.pdf(realYGrid, scale=0.001)
axes[0].plot(realXGrid, xDensity)
axes[4].plot(yDensity, realYGrid) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I run your code I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUIU5.png). This means part of your problem is that you have a different style set (e.g. seaborn's white style or similar). The question does not allow to know how you activated this style.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've added the style sheet information.

Comment: Yep, so remove that style.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend plotting the image in the actual data coordinates. This allows to use the same limits for the marginal distribution plots.
To get the spacings correct you could just give up the equal aspect ratio of the image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

nX, nY = 50, 70
realXGrid = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, nX)
realYGrid = np.linspace(-1, 1, nY)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(realXGrid, realYGrid, indexing='ij')
Z = XX * 3 - YY*5

# prepare figure/grid
fig5 = plt.figure()
widths = [1, 0.1, 0.1]
heights = [0.1, 1]
matAx = 3
caxAx = 5
spec5 = fig5.add_gridspec(ncols=3, nrows=2, width_ratios=widths,
                      height_ratios=heights, hspace=0, wspace=0)
axes = []
for row in range(2):
    for col in range(3):
        ax = fig5.add_subplot(spec5[row, col])
        axes.append(ax)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    if i != matAx:
        ax.axis('off')
    else:
        ax.grid(False)
        ax.patch.set_edgecolor('black')
        ax.patch.set_linewidth('1')

# plot    
dx = np.diff(realXGrid)[0]
dy = np.diff(realYGrid)[0]
extent = [realXGrid[0]-dx/2, realXGrid[-1]+dx/2, 
          realYGrid[0]-dx/2, realYGrid[-1]+dx/2]
im = axes[matAx].imshow(Z, cmap='RdGy', origin='lower', aspect="auto",
                         extent=extent)
#axes[matAx].axis('image')
fig5.colorbar(im, ax=axes[caxAx], orientation='vertical', fraction=1)

xDensity = norm.pdf(realXGrid, scale=0.1)
yDensity = norm.pdf(realYGrid, scale=0.001)
axes[0].plot(realXGrid, xDensity)
axes[4].plot(yDensity, realYGrid) 
axes[0].set_xlim(*extent[:2])
axes[4].set_ylim(*extent[2:])
plt.show()
```

[image]